# Trouble testing for an error thrown from AASM gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, aasm

I'm having trouble testing for a thrown AASM error.

Here is my controller method:

```
# controllers/jobs_controller.rb
def change_state
  respond_to do |format|
    if @job.close && @job.save
      format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job has been closed.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @job }
    else
      format.html { render :show, notice: 'Job could not be closed.' }
      format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

My spec looks like this:

```
# spec/controllers/jobs_controller_spec.rb
describe "POST #change_state" do
  it "cannot transition job from closed" do
    job.aasm_state = "closed"
    job.save!
    post :change_state, params: {id: job.hash_id, user_id: user.id}
    expect { response }.to raise_error(AASM::InvalidTransition)
  end
end
```

The test fails (with the expected/desired failure):

```
Failure/Error: if @job.close && @job.save     
AASM::InvalidTransition:Event 'close' cannot transition from 'closed'.
```

I'm just unable to figure out the right syntax to pass the test. I've tried a few variations of the `expect` line but can't seem to piece it together.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/aasm/aasm/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AASM%3A%3AInvalidTransition%3AEvent&type=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is happening before the `expect` statement. Try it:

```
expect {
  post(:change_state, params: { id: job.hash_id, user_id: user.id })
}.to(
  raise_error(AASM::InvalidTransition)
)
```

Comment: Do you know how I might also test `have_http_status(:error)`? I cannot seem to get around the error: `You must pass an argument rather than a block to use the provided matcher (respond with an error status code (5xx)), or the matcher must implement `supports_block_expectations?`.`

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. However, if you're successfully testing the exception, I think you can trust that Rails will render the correct status code.